# OPENCART: Blog module doesn't invite picture Why?

Tags: http-status-code-404, opencart, http-status-code-410

I have a Wordpress blog module installed on my Opencart 2.2.0.0 site. Links are working, but it does not show the thumbnail pictures related to the specific articles. GTmetrix shows 404/410 error. How can I solve 404/410 errors without turning off the module?

I checked the .php and .tpl files. It seems okay for me (I am not an expert...)

```
    <?php foreach($blogs as $blog){ ?>
  <div class="product-layout col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="product-thumb transition" style="height:138px;">
      <div class="image" ><a href="<?php echo $blog['href']; ?>"><img style="height:130px;" src="<?php echo $blog['thumb']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $blog['name']; ?>" title="<?php echo $blog['title']; ?>" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
      </div>
```

[Footer of the site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZWRn.png)

Comment: please upload with error screenshot  ? i can not understand what you say ?

Comment: I added the screenshot. In the footer this part shows articles from the Wordpress blog on the Opencart site. The opening picture of the specific articles should be visible in the boxes, however it only displays the author name of the specific article. This is the issue.

Comment: print_r($blogs); or echo $blogs; before foreach loop

Comment: otherwise send me your blog url. i will check what proper issue

Comment: It did not work out. The blog url: potompenz.hu/blog